# error when opening video in titanium

Tags: iphone, video, titanium

I've been working in Titanium appaccelerator and now I'm trying to open a video in it.

I've used the following code:

```
movieWindow.js

function displayVideo()
{
   var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   width:200,
   height:300,
   });

   var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
   url:"respigrandsoupir.mp4",
   width:300,
   height:200,
   top:50,
   left:50,
   backgroundColor:'#0f0'
   });

   window.add(activeMovie);
   activeMovie.play();

   return window;
}
```

My video `respigrandsoupir.mp4` is under the Resource folder. The problem is that when trying to run this method I get the following error:

> [WARN] Exception in event callback.  {    expressionBeginOffset = 159;
>   expressionCaretOffset = 173;
>       expressionEndOffset = 191;
>           line = 12;
>           message = "Result of expression 'Titanium.Media' [undefined] is not an object.";
>           name = TypeError;
>           sourceId = 238167336;
>           sourceURL = "file://localhost/Users/adrian/Documents/Titanium%20Studio%20Workspace/La%20Pause/Resources/movieWindow.js";
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Can one tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable answers, but Project->Clean solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a new object like Titanium.Media that you never used before, a clean is often required because Titanium builds a custom light version in the target folder.
If you don't clean, it will search in vain the widget in this folder.